# Encrypt new data with new key using attr_encrypted (overriding old data)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, encryption, openssl, attr-encrypted

I have to write a script that replace existing data with dummy (but valid) data. The script should only populate fields that are already populated on each record. I should NOT put dummy data into fields where no data existed previously. Can any one help to create a script?

I am using `attr_encrypted`, i wold like to overwrite the existing data with new data, using a new key. How can i do this?

My sample code for your reference:

License.where.not(license_number: nil).each do |number|
     number.update_attribute(:license_number, Faker::Number.number(6))
    end

When trying to update, i am getting `OpenSSL::Cipher::CipherError: bad decrypt` error
I believe it is due to the fact that `attr_encrypted` tries to `decrypt` first - which clearly won't work due to the key is different. Any idea is there to write the new data and `iv` with a new a new key?

Comment: The error you encouter isn't directly connected to the code you wrote. The script seems fine (we can probably improve on that, but that's not the origin of the error)

Comment: I'm with @Joel_Blum on this one. I'm guessing the cause is actually your `attr_encryptor` implementation. And is really unrelated to Faker or this script.

Comment: Could it be that you recently added `attr_encryptor` and have data in your database that predates it and is not encrypted or was encrypted by a different algorithm / salt / key?

Comment: @max .... that is exactly what the question asked, how to overwrite data that was encrypted by a different key. I have this same question. Maybe a way to disable the decrypt check?